# NGINX issues when matching partial location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm new in NGINX world and trying to learn.

I want to match:

- /mypage
- /mypage.php

but not

- /mypagewebsite

or anything else than the previous 2 matches

If I use `location ^~ /mypage {}` it matches also `/mypagewebsite` and I'm trying to avoid 2 block with exact match like `location = /mypage {}` and `location = /mypage.php {}`

How could I match just the first 2 locations without matching the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with regular expressions (regex).

```
location ~ ^/mypage(?:\.php)?$
```

#### Explanation

- `~` - [Tells nginx that we are using regex](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
- `^` - Marks the start of the string (uri must start right at this point)
- `(` and `)` - Parentheses are used for grouping
- `?:` - These symbols mean that nginx should't remember what's inside parentheses
- `?` - Means that the whole group (.php) is *optional*
- `$` - Means the end of the string (uri must end right here)

You may use online tools for creating and checking your regexes. For example, [this one](https://regex101.com/).